# Reports Builder in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, report, oraclereports

I am new to making the reports using Oracle 10g.
I have installed Oracle 10g (Database Express Edition). 
It  is run on my pc at port 8080
I am trying make the report. but i am not able to find the Reports Builder.

please help how i use report builder and suggest some good tutorials.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the Oracle Developer Suite?  Have you installed the Oracle Application Server?  Are you sure that you need to use Oracle Reports for whatever you are trying to do?

Comment: I have installed OracleXEUniv. its size is 206 mb. it is running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/ how i know it is supported to reports or not?
i want to learn to make the repots.

Comment: Having a database is a useful first step.  You would also need Oracle Developer Suite installed in order to get Oracle Reports Builder and you would probably need the Oracle Application Server in order to run Oracle Reports.  That's a reasonably hefty amount of software to try to run on your local machine.

Comment: Is i need two exe file of Oracle Developer Suite and Oracle Application Server. Can i download it at free.

Comment: Both Oracle Developer Suite and Oracle Application Server are available for download from OTN (http://otn.oracle.com) under the OTN license.  Assuming your use falls under the terms of the OTN license, you can use the software for free.  If you are developing reports for a production environment, though, you'll need additional licenses.

Comment: but i have no any license. i just want to learn forms and reports so that i can get the job. 
i have also installed SQL Server 2005 on my machine. Is SQL Server 2005 support to reports?

Comment: If you are merely trying to educate yourself, your use should generally fall under the terms of the OTN license so you would generally not need to pay anything for the license.  SQL Server 2005 is a completely different product from a different company-- it has nothing to do with getting Oracle Reports running.

Comment: Can you tell me please what i do so that i can fall under the terms of the OTN license.

Comment: Like I said, in general, if you are trying to educate yourself, you fall under the terms of the OTN license and can use any of the software on OTN free of charge.  You can look at the license agreement you accept before downloading the software to see the exact terms and conditions-- telling you exactly what you can and cannot do would take as much space as the license itself so you may as well read the actual terms of the actual license if that is a concern.

Comment: Good luck. You're going to need it, plus a lot of persistence :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the Oracle Developer Suite for Forms and Reports.. You can use the Report Builder from this to generate your Reports..